# Code snippet to create self-closing tag in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, emmet

I find it easier to work with self-closing tags when writing React code in VSCode. The default Emmet autocomplete behavior is to insert an explicit closing tag, eg. `<Recipe></Recipe>`, whereas I would like a way for autocomplete to issue a self-closing tag, eg. `<Recipe />`.

I've made snippets before but I don't know how to make the snippet prefix act on more general input. It needs to react to any capital lettered word. How would I create a snippet to accomplish this?

Comment: have you read the good VSC snippet doc

Comment: Yes, I've made snippets before too but I don't know how to make the snippet prefix act on more general input. It needs to react to any capital lettered word.

Comment: how do you know the Capital word has ended

Comment: Normally, a tab will cause the autocomplete to ensue, so that, or another keypress, would determine when the word ends

Answer (score 16):

To produce self-closing tag in Emmet, add closing slash after abbreviation, e.g. `Recipe/`

Comment: I don't think that this answers the question. OP was looking for an answer that shows how to end in `<Recipe/>` and not `<Recipe></Recipe>` which this answer leads to

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips).

It has a bug that does not allow you to use a regex trigger. After you install you have to add a single line to the file `out/completion.js`. See the [pull request](https://github.com/draivin/hsnips/pull/76) I made.

In your `html.hsnips` file add the following snippet:

```
snippet `[A-Z][a-z0-9]+$` "Self Close Tag"
`` rv = `<${m[0]} />` ``
endsnippet
```